# global name 'join' is not defined django

Tags: python, django

I am using the following

```
clear= join(('string', seed ,'Aviesta'));
```

it is giving me error :
global name 'join' is not defined.Please Hepl!

Comment: And the output you expect is...?

Comment: i want to make a random value using join.I mean i want to join these strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`join` is a `str` method, you need to call it on a `str` instance:

```
In [31]: str.join??
Type:       method_descriptor
String Form:<method 'join' of 'str' objects>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
S.join(iterable) -> string

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
iterable.  The separator between elements is S.
```

---

```
In [32]: ''.join(('string', 'seed' ,'Aviesta'))
Out[32]: 'stringseedAviesta'

In [33]: '_'.join(('string', 'seed' ,'Aviesta'))
Out[33]: 'string_seed_Aviesta'
```

Comment: thanks worked perfectly